# Professor used "The binary version of a function". Does that even exist?

Tags: python, function

Our professor used this in the assignment. I don't think "The binary version of a function" exist after searching about it in Google. What do you think it means?

> Say we have a function add that adds a bunch of numbers. Rather than
>   writing add(3, 5, 4, 1) we want to use currying to create an adder
>   function that can be extended using a chain of calls. We would then
>   have adder(3)(5)(4)(1)(). Let us assume we have the currying function
>   that can create this adder given the add2 function (**the binary version
>   of add**) and a start value. Let us call it curry. Then we have adder =
>   curry(add2, 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case ["binary function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_function) refers to an argument that accepts two arguments. In this case your professor is probably referring to something like this:

```
def add2(x, y):
    return x + y
    # equivalently: add2 = lambda x,y: x+y

def curry(func, num):
    def wrapped(*args):
        if len(args) == 0:
            return num
        elif len(args) > 1:
            raise TypeError('{} takes 1 positional argument but '
                            '{} were given'.format(
                                func.__name__, len(args)))
        arg = args[0]
        return curry(func, func(num, arg))
    return wrapped
```

Comment: I still didn't understand how it works. Could you suggest me some simple tutorials or reads to understand how it works? I'm lost when I try to track how it works.

Comment: @user4220128 [let's talk in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65886/binary-closure)

Comment: Isn't *args always null? Why not?

Answer (score 7):

I think he means a function that accepts only two arguments, so it just adds two numbers.  His example function `add(3, 5, 4, 1)` would be a function that accepts any number of arguments and adds them all, but `add2` would only accept two arguments, so `add2(3, 5)` would be 8.  "The binary version of a function" in this case means a [binary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_function) (a function accepting two arguments).

Answer (score 2):

@AdamSmith and @BrenBarn have already pointed out what [binary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_function) means. A simple and clear assignment solution can be write by using object instead of decorator.

```
class curry():
    def __init__(self, func, default):
        self._f = func
        self._default = default
    def __call__(self, val=None):
        if val is None:
            return self._default
        return curry(self._f,self._f(self._default,val))

print(curry(lambda x,y:x+y, 0)(3)(5)(4)(1)())
```

Neat and simple!

IMHO functors should be used only when the increase readability, simplicity or hide tedious work. In that case the object and functor implementations are really the same but the object version is more readable and straight to understand.